# Proof by contradiction : about the assumption that there are finitely many primes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

To prove by contradiction that there are infinitely many primes, we first assume there are finitely many primes.

It sounds to me that we can consider all primes in $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this assumption possible beacause of a ZFC axiom, that is, we take the set of all primes $\{x\in\mathbb{N}:x\text{ is a prime}\}$ and assume the set is finite?

(I did not know [Euclid's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) is a proof by cases, a direct proof method.)

Comment: Axiom schema of specification

Comment: The direct proof needn't be split into a prime vs. composite case analysis of $\,q = 1+p_1\cdots p_n$ (that it was done so by Euclid was likely due to language or logic limitations in those ancient times). Namely, since $\,q \ge 1\,$ it has a prime factor $p$, which can't be equal to any $p_i$ since they are all coprime to $\,q.\,$ QED, with no such case analysis. Unlike the proof by contradiction, the direct proof is *constructive*, i.e. it yields an algorithm to generate an infinite sequence of primes.

Comment: I removed the ENT tag since the question has little to do with number theory.

Comment: It is more like the ZFC axiom is possible because we believe the set is constructable in so many cases like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the axioms of ZFC guarantee the existence of the set of all primes in $\mathbb{N}$.

Indeed, in ZFC the [axiom scheme of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (also known as axiom scheme of separation, or axiom scheme of comprehension) says that:

$$\tag{1}
    \forall w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n}\,\forall A\,\exists B\,\forall x\,(x\in B\Leftrightarrow [x\in A\land \varphi (x,w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n},A)])
$$

where $\varphi$ is any formula in the language of set theory with free variables among $x, w_1, ..., w_n, A$ ($B$ does not occur free in $φ$).

Now, instantiate $(1)$ with $n=0$ and $A = \mathbb{N}$ (it exists in ZFC because of the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity)), and with the formula $\varphi(x)$ that says that $x$ is prime (it can easily be expressed in the language of set theory).
It yields
$$
\exists B  \, \forall x (x \in B \Leftrightarrow (x \in \mathbb{N} \land x \text{ is prime})) 
$$
So, in ZFC there exists a set $B$ that is nothing but $\{x \in \mathbb{N} : x \text{ is a prime}\}$.

---

In ZFC, the axiom scheme of specification is not assumed as axiom because it can be derived from another axiom scheme in ZFC, the [axiom scheme of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Relation_to_the_axiom_schema_of_replacement).